# Windows application - SMS Status callback events for Twilio to update status in DB

Tags: c#, wpf, twilio, twilio-api

In my windows application, I am using Twilio for SMS implementation and I need to save the status in DB.
I can able to send SMS using Twilio but when I try to get the status callback I can see the URI defined for callback in Twilio.
But I am using Windows application and no URI will be there.

Please suggest how can achieve this, Is there any events for callback status update.?

My code is:

```
TwilioClient.Init(username, password);
messageResource = await MessageResource.CreateAsync(
                    to: new PhoneNumber(ToNumber),
                    from: new PhoneNumber(FromNumber),
                    body: body
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We do not recommend that you make API calls to the Twilio API from within client side applications. When you make an API call from a client side application you must make the account credentials available within the client and a malicious user could extract the credentials and abuse the account.

Instead, we recommend that you make the API calls from a server, where you can keep your credentials secure, and that you access your server using an authenticated session from your client-side application.

Once you implement a server-side component, you can then open up a URL at which you can receive status callback webhooks and forward those onto your client-side application however you want.

Finally, status callbacks are the best way to get the most up to date information about your messages, but you could also poll the [message resource API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource) to check for status updates.

Comment: HI, Thanks for your reply, but here it an class library hence it don't have a client-server model, anyone can use my class library, hence I don't know which application is consuming and I don't have any redirect URI

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say it is a "class library". Could you explain further?

Comment: I am developing a class library (notification component) that send SMS and makes status entry in DB.  This library can be consumed by web/windows application. and I don't know who is consuming my class library and the status callback URL. my question is, instead of URI any call back event available in Twilio or how to achieve this

Comment: I do not recommend you continue with that work. It sounds to me as though you will need the application to store a Twilio Account SID and Auth Token and I cannot recommend that as it could be recovered from the code and abused. You should only make API calls to Twilio from a machine where the credentials can be securely stored, such as a server-side application. This class library is not a good idea and is a potential security issue.